# How to find rails route pattern from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rack

Given a rack request where I know the path, e.g. `/things/1`, how can I get the route reference e.g. `/things/:id`?

I can use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` to get the controller and action, but I’m explicitly looking for an obfuscated path.

Is there anyway to get the recognized route given a controller#action, maybe?

Comment: `/things/:id` is the pattern used to match the URI and has nothing to do with obfuscation. Rails doesn't actually provide the matched route object for a given request AFAIK so whatever you're doing I would consider a different path forward.

Comment: Maybe obfuscation is used incorrectly here. This is for observability purposes. Given url paths that have unbounded alphanumeric parts, I’m looking for the path with the rails parameter keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place I knew where that information is available is `bin/rails routes`. It's using inspector to collect all the information:

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/inspector.rb*

Maybe there is something else you'll find there. But I extracted the main bit that you're asking for:

```rb
# in a controller or a template

<% request.routes.router.recognize(request) do |route, _params| %>
  <%= route.path.spec.to_s %> # => /users/:id(.:format)
<% end %>
```

```rb
# in a console

>> Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(
  ActionDispatch::Request.new(Rack::MockRequest.env_for("/users/1/edit", method: :get))
) {}.map {|_,_,route| route.path.spec.to_s }
=> ["/users/:id/edit(.:format)"]
```

`route` here is `ActionDispatch::Journey::Route` instance which has all the information about a route.

---

I don't have even a remote clue what this does, but it does it:

```rb
>> Rails.application.routes.routes.simulator.memos("/users/1/edit").first.ast.to_s
=> "/users/:id/edit(.:format)"

# NOTE: if route doesn't match it will `yield` and raise
# no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
# just rescue or give it an empty block.
```

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/gtg/simulator.rb#L25*

Answer (score 1):

Following up [the answer from Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883063/10871073): on Rails 7.1, I had the error:

> undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass

What worked for me:

```
Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(
      ActionDispatch::Request.new(Rack::MockRequest.env_for("/users/1/edit", method: :get))
    ) {}.map { |route| route.path.spec.to_s }
```